# Django settings configure databases with two engines

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, django-settings

I'm trying to run DJango with postgresql and postgis

for Django & postgresql I configures the `setting.py` file as follows

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'myDatabaseName',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'MyPassword',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

but looking at the tutorial of Django geo example shows to use this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
         'NAME': 'geodjango',
         'USER': 'geo',
     }
}
```

**The Problem:** I need both engines to work on the same database as I'm using postgresql with the postgis extension and I'd like to define a table with a geographic column like this:

```
MapLocation GEOGRAPHY(POINT)
```

and refer to it from Django like this `maplocation = models.PointField()`

obviously i need a mash of both engines with the rest as mentioned above in 'default' I just don't know how to make it work

Comment: Review the documentation on [supporting multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/) in Django.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @JosephPaetz i've edited my question, I need both engines to work on the same database

Comment: @Mingyu the error i get is: File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 202, in db_type
    return connection.ops.geo_db_type(self)
AttributeError: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type'

Comment: Have you installed `postgis`?

Comment: @Mingyu yes,if i create a table directly in psql it works fine including populating it with data, but i have to map the Django model to it.

Answer (score 2):

In Django, you may define multiple database connections:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'app_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'USER': 'postgres_user',
        'PASSWORD': 's3krit'
    },
    'users': {
        'NAME': 'user_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'priv4te'
    }
}
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#defining-your-databases

Comment: aren't you referring to two different databases? mine is the same postgresql database with the postgis extension so in the table i can add a geographic column like this MapLocation GEOGRAPHY(POINT)

Comment: From your question, it's not clear whether you have one or more databases.  If you only have one database connection, it seems you already have the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I maybe a bit late, but if anyone else stumbles upon this link, here's how i did it:

in your settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'NAME': 'app_data',
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'USER': 'postgres_user',
    'PASSWORD': 's3krit'
},
'location': {
    'NAME': 'app_data',
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',,
    'USER': 'postgres_user',
    'PASSWORD': 's3krit'
}
```

}

So we only changed the engine in settings.

Now, we need to tell the database to write and read geography data from the second database.

For that, in your models.py, lets say you have a Location class:

```
class Location(models.Model):
location_points = models.PointField(default=Point(0,0))
address = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
label = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'location'
```

Note the db_table attribute in the Meta class, this is necessary.

Now you need to define database router to use the 'location' database whenever the db_table is 'location'.

Here's how the router class should look like:

```
class DbRouter(object):
"""
A router to control all database operations on models in the
auth application.
"""
def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Attempts to read location models go to location database.
    """
    if model._meta.db_table == 'location':
        return 'location'
    return 'default'

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Attempts to write location models go to the location database.
    """
    if model._meta.db_table == 'location':
        return 'location'
    return 'default'


def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    """
    allow relations involving the location database
    """
    return True
```

You are now good to go, save the router class in a file named dbrouter.py inside your app.

And in your settings.py file, add this:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['app_name.dbrouters.DbRouter', ]
```