# using postgis and multi tenancy with django

Tags: django, multi-tenant, geodjango

i have to create an app that uses multi tenancy separated by country [ie: colombia.myapp.com, usa.myapp.com, etc] and i want to use the geoDjango module with PostGIS. For my multi tenant i'm using django-tenant-schemas, but both solutions change the engine of the postgres database.

**PROBLEM:**
it's there a way to use two separated engines over the same database in django? or connect to the same database with the two engines without generate a conflict in the database and work with both Multi Tenancy and GeoDjango?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, you only have to be careful to always indicate the database you want to use.

**settings.py**:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'users': {
        'NAME': 'user_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'superS3cret'
    },
    'customers': {
        'NAME': 'customer_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_cust',
        'PASSWORD': 'veryPriv@ate'
    }
}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: thanks a lot, but, my idea is use the same database different engine, is that possible? something like

DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'users': {
        'NAME': 'database',
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'USER': 'postgresuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'superS3cret'
    },
    'customers': {
        'NAME': 'database',
        'ENGINE': 'tenant_schemas.postgresql_backend',
        'USER': 'postgresuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'superS3cret'
    }
}

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Comment: @beren5000 Did it work? I am trying to use timescaledb and Postgis. Using 2 databases is not an option since I want to have relationships bw tables.

Comment: Anyone coming here after today, read this answer, this answers your question in detail:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305197/django-settings-configure-databases-with-two-engines/68679298#68679298